# trying to understand how regex works

Tags: r, regex

I'm learning about regex expressions and confused by how this whole field works. I've taken an example from a tutorial [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and pasted it into https://regexr.com/.

The regex below is supposed to capture email addresses but it doesn't seem to work, at least as is.

I'm posting here in the hopes that there's a simple explanation I might look further into.

From the tutorial website, I gleaned that there are different "flavors" of regex. From the regexr.com site, it seems I have the option to choose a JavaScript or PCRE engine (I assume engine is a synonym for flavor). It doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
```

[image]

Ultimately I'm working in R so have added the R tag to this post. I suspect R may use yet a different flavour from the one above.

Comment: `"[A-Z]"` matches only capital letters between A and Z. If you need to capture lowercase, as is typical in email addresses including the one in your test text, use `"[A-Za-z]"` or `"[:alpha:]"`

Comment: or you might as well just use [:alnum:] to capture the 0-9 as well while you're at it.

Comment: And just because I got stuck on it in the past, notice that you'll need it to be `[[:alnum:]._%+-]`

Comment: @camille thank you (obvious now). "[A-Za-z]" works but not "[:alpha:]"

Comment: @iod: thanks. yes works in PCRE (not in JavaScript) on regexr.com.

Comment: FTR: UPDATE: correction it works with [[::alpha::]] as in `\b[[:alpha:]]+@[[:alpha:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,}\b` under PCRE.

Comment: Albeit a great source for learning regex, https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html failed to mention that the `/i` flag is assumed; `/i` tells the regex engine to be case-insensitive. At https://regexr.com/ just click that "Flags" dropdown and enable case-insensitive.